# SVN getting list of locally modified in XML format without unversioned

Tags: svn

Using SVN, I need to only get a list of files that was modified locally.

The following command gives that to me:

`svn status --quiet`

However I wrote an XML parser to parser svn status output, thus I add --xml to the above command so it looks like this:

`svn status --quiet --xml`

This command gives different output that also included a bunch of unversioned files. How could that be? The --xml switch should only change the output format shouldn't it?

How to get only locally modified files in XML format?

Comment: It might be worth sending this to the svn users mailing list to inquire about whether it's a bug.

Comment: Removed windows tag- happens on linux 1.7.x client (and server) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is odd... Like you I was surprised.  The quickest path will likely be to change your parser to ignore things that have `item="unversioned"` in `<wc-status>`

Comment: Thank, I added an ignore a bit later down on the output of the parser. But you are right, makes sense to throw it out as early as possible.